# Create a new release using VSTEAM

Tags: powershell

I am using VSTEAM to connect to TFS and queuing some things and its working.
I want to create a new release automatically. I have the release definition ID and also got the parameters but don't know how to complete the mission.
When I am trying to do Add-VSTeamRelease -DefinitionId 2936 , ArtifactAlias is required and I dont know what does it means so I put an empty string. Afterward I need to supply -BuildId and I don't know how to get it.
I need to add those parameters as you can see below:
Under Pipelines: Only the fist should be marked
Under Variables there are 3 parameters that need to changed

[image]

Get-VSTeamReleaseDefinition -Id 2936 -raw give the following:

[image]

I tried to read this but still I don't know how to continue

https://methodsandpractices.github.io/vsteam-docs/docs/modules/vsteam/commands/Add-VSTeamRelease/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break the requirement,

- `ArtifactAlias` is the artifact source that you attach to release pipeline. It can be your build pipeline artifacts or Azure Git etc. Please take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/artifacts?view=azure-devops#artifact-sources).
- In the below pic I've attached artifact from a build pipeline named `Demo-CI` and the artifact name is `_Demo-CI` (and of course it is based on what you name it).

[Artifact Alias Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84dn9.png)

- You need to hook 4 different APIs to complete this.
- You can either use `Get-VSTeamBuild` to get the list of build or you can get a particular build with build id. If you don't know the build id, please navigate to **Pipelines** section in Azure DevOps and select the build pipeline/definition and click on any build to get the build id from url.
  [https://dev.azure.com/organization/project/_build/results?buildId=`3`&view=results](https://dev.azure.com/organization/project/_build/results?buildId=%603%60&view=results).
  This is one way of getting the build id and based on the build number format that you've set.
- You can also get the build id from build pipeline name. See example below,

```
C:\> Get-VSTeamBuild | ? { $_.DefinitionName -eq 'Demo-CI' }

Definition Build Number Result    Id
---------- ------------ ------    --
Demo-CI    16          canceled   16
Demo-CI    18          succeeded  18
```

- Once you have the build id, you can get the artifact alias from cmdlet `Get-VSTeamReleaseDefinition`.

```
C:\> Set-VSTeamAccount -Account "organization" -PersonalAccessToken "personal access token"
C:\> Set-VSTeamDefaultProject "project name"
# This will give you the build definition object
C:\> $def = Get-VSTeamReleaseDefinition -Id 2936
# Get the artifact source from the release pipeline/definition
# This gives you an array of artifact sources.
C:\> $def.Artifacts
# Assuming that you have only one artifact source attached to the pipeline.
C:\> $def.Artifacts[0].alias
```

- Combining the above steps

```
C:\> $buildId = Get-VSTeamBuild | ? { $_.DefinitionName -eq 'Demo-CI' } | Select -First 1 -Expand Id
C:\> $def = Get-VSTeamReleaseDefinition -Id 2936
C:\> $artifactAlias = $def.Artifacts[0].alias
C:\> Add-VSTeamRelease -ArtifactAlias $artifactAlias -BuildId $buildId -DefinitionId $def.Id
```

- `Add-VSTeamRelease` will return a release object. You can then use it to update the variables. Note that variables is of type `PSCustomObject` and you can refer the example shown [here](https://methodsandpractices.github.io/vsteam-docs/docs/modules/vsteam/commands/Update-VSTeamRelease/#example-2) to do that.

```
C:\> $release = Add-VSTeamRelease -ArtifactAlias $artifactAlias -BuildId $buildId -DefinitionId $def.Id
C:\> $r = Get-VSTeamRelease -Id $release.Id -Raw
C:\> $r.variables.service.value = 'New Service Here'
C:\> Update-VSTeamRelease -Release $r -Id $r.id
```

- The above example will update your release created.

Here is an example powershell script to deploy code - [Invoke-AzureDevOpsPipeline.ps1](https://github.com/hkarthik7/Common-PowerShell-Scripts/blob/master/Invoke-AzureDevOpsPipeline.ps1). This triggers build pipeline and waits for build to complete and then triggers release pipeline. You may want to tweak accordingly to suit your purpose.